# Show a div based on another div

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I've a research function that depends on many arguments, in order to lead the user , I want to first show a div that contains a dropdown list and two text inputs , when the user is done filling these , I want to show the second div that contains a dropdown list and a datepicker , when he's done I'd like to show the button.
The result will be displayed in a table, I want this table to be shown when the button is clicked.

For now I show everything from the start, like this :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <label> Choose an environment </label> <br>
                <select [(ngModel)]="env" required (change)="onChangeEnv($event.target.value.toLowerCase())">
                    <option selected>Choose an environment</option>
                    <option  *ngFor="let x of environmentsTable"  >
                        {{x.nom | uppercase}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label>Username</label> <br>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" />
                <br>
                <label>Password</label> <br>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <label> Choose a type </label> <br>
                <select [(ngModel)]="type" required (change)="onChange($event.target.value.toLowerCase())">
                    <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a type</option>
                    <option  *ngFor="let x of typesTable"  >
                        {{x.nom_type | uppercase}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="x.checked" (change)="foo()">
                {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
            </div>
            <dp-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [config]="dateConfig"></dp-date-picker>

            <br>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=postParams() style="margin-left:40%;margin-right:40%">
                Search</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Entité</th>
                    <th>Modifié par</th>
                    <th>Date de modification</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let x of respTest">
                    <th>{{x.Type}}</th>
                    <td>{{x.Entit}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Modif}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.DateModif}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.. This sounds like a pretty extensive usage of a bunch of `*ngIf` directives.

On your component.ts, you should initialise the `env`, `username` and `password` properties

```
env: string = undefined;
username: string = undefined;
password: string = undefined;
```

Then, we wrap the second div that contains the datepicker and dropdownlist with  `*ngIf="env && username && password"`, which will ensure that the div is only shown once the above 3 properties have a value.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="env && username && password">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <label> Choose a type </label> <br>
            <select [(ngModel)]="type" required (change)="onChange($event.target.value.toLowerCase())">
                <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a type</option>
                <option  *ngFor="let x of typesTable"  >
                    {{x.nom_type | uppercase}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let x of groupesTable">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="x.checked" (change)="foo()">
            {{x.nom_groupe | uppercase}}
        </div>
        <dp-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [config]="dateConfig"></dp-date-picker>

        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the same logic to handle the rest of your component when it comes to showing/hiding `<div>`s.

As for the button,

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=postParams() style="margin-left:40%;margin-right:40%">Search</button>
```

What you can do is, to include another property called `showTable`, which will be toggled to `true` when the button is clicked.

```
showTable: boolean = true;

postParams() {
  this.showTable = true;
  // handle the rest
}
```

Then, we add `*ngIf="showTable"` to the div the wraps the table, such that the table will only be displayed when the button is clicked.

```
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar" *ngIf="showTable">
  <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Entité</th>
                <th>Modifié par</th>
                <th>Date de modification</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let x of respTest">
                <th>{{x.Type}}</th>
                <td>{{x.Entit}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Modif}}</td>
                <td>{{x.DateModif}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I were you, I would make use of Angular's [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) to handle this situation. But that is another answer for another day!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to base the second div's visibility on the validity of a reactive form, provided all of the fields are required.

Then your logic is simply:

```
<div id="firstDiv">...</div>
<div id="secondDiv" *ngIf="form.valid">...</div>
```

Once the form is valid, the second div will become visible, and you don't have to watch the individual fields on the firm or component properties for value changes.